# CMake building a project for two different targets with different build-tools

Tags: cmake

I have a project that I compile to two very different target (desktop and web-assembly), using a different environment, different compiler and different parameters.

So far I have two CMakeLists files, building into two different folders. But that forces me to copy-paste the list of source files, some configuration about the version etc. And they cannot be in the same folder because of the fixed name for CMakeLists files.

I would like to have a common cmake file that contains all the shared project configuration, while configuring the build differently depending on an option for example, and including one of the two sub-cmake files that would be specific to each build.

What is the modern-cmake strategy to do this?
I see answers about debug/release builds or shared/static but I fail to understand one best practice of how to define different targets+buildchains depending on an option.

Should I use [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) and an [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html)?
Is passing the shared configuration and source files as [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) a good practice?

Comment: This is too broad, too vague. `How can I do this?` merge into one cmake. Write two configurations. Start doing it, and when you have a problem, that you can't solve after exhaustive research, ask the question about that specific problem. You might be interested in a cmake toolchain file.

Comment: @KamilCuk I know the question is vague but it's because I'm looking for an architecture/strategy here and not solutions to specific problems. I already have the two configurations but I could not find any clear way of including them with a conditional option.